# Importing Runtime-Configurable JSON in Typescript and Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have a runtime translation system in place in my application, which before switching to Angular 7 was using http requests to load a JSON file filled with translations, like the below:

```
loadLanguage(lang: string) {
    this.http.get('assets/lang/' + lang + '.json)
        .toPromise()
        .then((translations) => this.translations = translations; ) 
}
```

As part of an upgrade to Angular 7 I decided to try out importing the json directly rather than using http to get it. This is the new way I've implemented it:

```
async loadLanguage(lang: string) {
    this.translations = await import('assets/lang/' + lang + '.json);
}
```

This works the way I would expect in terms of changing the language but the problem I am having is changing the JSON files after compilation has no effect on the output of the import.

From the bundle produced by the compilation it looks like all of the imported files are being compiled into chunks which are then loaded when I ask for that particular json file. Am I just getting the wrong idea with these imports and how they work when used with webpack or is there something obvious that I have missed when refactoring my solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should be doing this. As import() gets converted to required() post compilation. plus this is not a Angular feature it's a TypeScript feature.
here a very nice and detailed article on Type https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2018/01/14/typescript-2-4-dynamic-import-expressions

As a recommendation you should be using http calls to download dynamic runtime configuration.

Comment: Yeah, on typing this question out I had thought that I might had been mistaken trying to use TS dynamic imports for my config. Thanks for your quick reply.